# How to get row numbers of MySQL subquery GROUP BY results?

Tags: mysql

I am confused on how to use this MySQL query as a subquery to get the successive number of the GROUP BY results. GROUP BY still has the row number of the query before GROUP BY executes, hence the row_count of 14 and 1 as shown in the image below.

```
SET @row_count:=0;
SELECT @row_count:=@row_count+1 AS row_count,column_id, type
FROM mt_report_filters
WHERE report_id = 2
GROUP BY column_id
```

[image: MySQL Results]

I am trying to build it into a subquery to obtain the successive row_count 1 and 2 with this logic, but this is incorrect.

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number FROM t1, column_id, type
FROM(
    SELECT column_id, type
    FROM mt_report_filters
    WHERE report_id = 2
    GROUP BY column_id
    AS t1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a bit confused about what do you need. Do you want to retrieve each row of the column `row_count` or trying to `sum` their values?

Comment: Why don't you use: `select count(column_id) from table group by column_id`? (See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e682c/3).

Comment: I am attempting to get a row number of unique Column ID's that I am binding to an array, not counting the Column ID's. For example, Row #: 1, 2, 3, and so on for any Column ID. My end goal is to access the array to retrieve the Column ID that I will refer to for values matching the Column ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin was giving me the error message: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. From there I had an idea that I need the table created from the subquery to be aliased so I just added 'AS t1' at the end.

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, column_id, type 
FROM (
    SELECT column_id, type 
    FROM mt_report_filters
    WHERE report_id = 2
    GROUP BY column_id) AS t1
```

[image: Row Number]

Comment: Yep, I'm all set! Thanks!